# Angular 4 - router outlet breaks and contains multiple components (production only)

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I have an interesting issue where navigating to a page in my angular application causes both components (the one I was navigating from and the one I am navigating to) on the same page.

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<component1></component1>
<component2></component2>
```

The second component breaks, though the constructor fires.  There are no errors and everything fails silently.

The worst thing about this is that it only happens once in awhile (usually on the first refresh or on a new incognito window), and is fairly hard to reproduce.

Has anyone seen this before? Or any case where  contains multiple routes?

Comment: funny you should say...and only 20 hours ago...i'm out looking for answers to the same problem...but my situation isn't isolated to production

Comment: may be share in plunk?